# How does the Java getCodeBase() method work?

Tags: java, applet

So I learned about the getCodeBase() method today in my programming class and to be honest, I'm really interested in it and how it works in general. All I know is that it finds the directory of where the source code is stored and it is mostly used in applets. But anyone explaining, in detail, how it actually works like the technicalities and such, I would be super grateful! By the way, I started Java 6 months ago. Thanks!

This is what I learned, just to put a little code in here.

```
cards[0] = getImage( getCodeBase(), "cards_gif/1.gif" );
```

getCodeBase() in this case, is used to initalize a part of an array to a image.

Comment: Where is that method declared?

Comment: In my applet code that initalizes a part of an array to a picture.

Comment: In what class is that method declared? Did you write it? Is it part of your source code or is it provided by some other library, JDK or otherwise?

Comment: It is my own source code. I imported an Image class.

Comment: Are you asking us what your custom method, which you haven't posted here, is doing?

Comment: No no no. Just in general, what does the getCodeBase() method do?

Comment: If you wrote it, how are we supposed to know?

Comment: Should I edit the question?

Comment: Yes, provide details about what `getCodeBase()` is.

Comment: Say you had `"somestring".length()`. The method `lenght()` is declared in the class `String`. Where is the method `getCodeBase()` declared?

Comment: the URL class `import java.net.URL`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> getDocumentBase()

Gets the *URL of the document in which this applet is embedded*.

For example, suppose an applet is contained within the document:

```
http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/1.2/index.html
```

The document base is:

```
http://java.sun.com/products/jdk/1.2/index.html
```

> getCodeBase()

Gets the *base URL*. This is the URL of the *directory* which contains this applet.

---

I want to **delete** this post, but can't do it as it's accepted.

Comment: Cool! This explained it

Comment: I edited your post. I added a new tag Applet and method tag is removed to make it more clear for others.

Comment: This answer isn't correct. It returns whatever the codebase was that was specified in the HTML, or its default. It has nothing to do with project structures.

Comment: Same as the document base I believe.

Comment: Read again what [getDocumentBase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getDocumentBase%28%29) returns. Gets the URL of the document in which this applet is embedded.

Comment: Read again what I wrote. If you specify it in the HTML it isn't defaulted to the document base, so the document base is irrelevant. The codebase isn't even necessarily a directory. It can be a JAR file, or a list of them.

Comment: @EJP I am trying to relate it with the class-path here. Where the image file will be looked in case of applet.

Comment: @Braj If you have to ask questions about this stuff you shouldn't be answering them as well. Ask your own question.

Comment: I want to delete the post but can't do it

Comment: @EJP Please can you help me to delete this answer.

Answer (score 2):

It returns whatever the codebase was that was specified in the HTML, or its default.